# Wordpress installation on LAMP: what happens if I move the server?

Tags: apache-http-server, raspbian, wordpress

I have a wordpress installation on a Raspberry Pi 3 with Apache2. Online I found a lot of tutorials and articles on how to correctly migrate a wordpress site from one server to another. In my case, however, I moved the raspberry pi to another house but the wordpress site remained on the the same machine.

The only thing that changed is my public IP: from the old house where I had a static public IP, to the new one where I have a dynamic IP and I set up a DDNS service.

I changed `ServerName` in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/{mywebsite}.conf` accordingly, and updated the values of `siteurl` and `home` in my database (as explained [in this article](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/#changing-the-url-directly-in-the-database)), but my site is still unreachable locally and remotely.

Should I migrate the wordpress installation to a new instance within the same physical server? It does not make a lot of sense to me but something is clearly eluding me so...

EDIT: Within the same apache instance I have another website that I coded from scratch and works, so to me that means this is a Wordpress issue. What I do not get is if it is due to the change of the server's physical location.

Comment: You may want to try and narrow the problem slightly by pointing your setup to a directory root other than Wordpress. If that doesn't work, then you know the issue is with your configuration outside Wordpress (and vice versa, if it does work, you have a Wordpress issue).

Comment: Within the same apache instance I have another website that I coded from scratch and it works, so to me that means this is a Wordpress issue. What I do not get is if it is due to the change of the server's physical location... I will update the question to include this bit

Comment: If you mysqldump your database to a txt file, does it contain any references to the old address? Anything in your apache/php error logs?